# How to update date display format in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, date-format, kibana-5, timelion

I want to change the date display format in kibana. Kibana provides this feature via moment.js, but not enough documentation available, or at least it doesn't work properly.[image]

Current date format: "MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss.SSS"
Required date format: "DD MMM YY" (like 29 July 17)

I tried changing the date format of the Date field in "Management" section, but that didn't work. (do I need to restart the server or something to make it work)
Or 
Where am I going wrong
Or 
What are some other ways to change date display format.
and What does popularity of the field do here ?

Some screenshots for the reference.

[image: Date Display format]

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I had to fix it in the scripts feeding data to elasticsearch itself.

Comment: How did you fix it? Your answer needs more detail.

Comment: So I have python scripts feeding data into elasticsearch. I changed the time format from unix time to above mentioned format and then pushed it to elasticsearch. It was not on the elasticsearch or kibana side. time.strftime("%d %b %Y", ts)